# Remove object from json based on one of its properties

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Let's say I have in a MySQL 8 column JSON data like this:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "test1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "test2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "test3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now let's say I want to remove the object with id=2 from the array using the MySQL function `JSON_REMOVE`. How would the path selector for `JSON_REMOVE` look like?

Unfortunately the MySQL documentation does not contain a lot of information about it's Json-Path capabilites. Or maybe it does not even support this scenario?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax

---

### Update

@Barmar suggests in the comments to use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) to turn the json array into a table which can be filtered by id, and then bring back the filtered table into json world using [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg).

The approach sounds promising, and I was able to figure out the first part:

```
SET @j = '{ "values": [ { "id": 1, "value": "test1" }, { "id": 2, "value": "test2" }, { "id": 3, "value": "test3" } ] }';
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(@j, '$.values[*]' COLUMNS (id INT PATH '$.id', value LONGTEXT PATH '$.value')) as jt WHERE id != 2;
```

However I couldn't figure out how to build the json array again using [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg). The example in the documentation demonstrates how to build a json array of "singular values". But I can't figure out how to build a json array of objects, where every object contains data from multiple columns of my temporary table.

Can anyone help here? (Or propose a completely different approach?)

Comment: Use `JSON_TABLE()` to convert the array to a table. Then use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` with a subquery that uses `WHERE id != 2` to create a new array with that element removed.

Comment: Your `id` property has numeric datatype, so you cannot use JSON_SEARCH (which searches for sting-type data only) and build the path of the array element to be removed. Use the method described by @Barmar, it is the most simple way.